# Using Microsoft.bot.Connector.DirectLine in a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, bots, direct-line-botframework

I am currently trying to communicate with a bot (made using Microsoft Bot Framework) with a UWP app.

I am getting

`Severity Code Description  Project File Lin Suppression State
Error Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={my token}.'  {project name and path}`

When i build the project after installing the Microsoft.bot.Connector.DirectLine nuget.

I tried this in a completely blank UWP app. (with the default blank page).

I tried restarting Visual studio and the project, as well as creating a new one.

I am using version 3.0.2 of the nuget but i tried all version to 3.0.0 included.
Both windows and Visual studio are up to date. I have also disabled my antivirus.

I am running out of idea to try to solve this issue. Do you have an idea of other things to try ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install the version *2.0.0.0* or above of this nuget package *Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime*